# @State not changing when variable is a function type

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, state

I created a custom implementation of `onTapGesture(_:)` for a custom view, however, it doesn't work as intended. I have an `@State` property called `action` which gets called at the end of the button press. It's supposed to function as "additional functionality" to whatever the button does. For some strange reason, when I update the `action` property it isn't reflected.

```
ShowAlertButton()
                .onTapGestureCustom {
                    print("*silent alarm*")
                    // I expect the view to print "*silent alarm*" when I press "sound alarm"
                    // However, it continues to print "ALERT!!!" which is the default value
                }
```

```
struct ShowAlertButton: View {
    @State private var action: () -> Void = { print("ALERT!!!") }  // << default value
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // ... some code
            action()  // << additional functionality
        } label: {
            Text("Sound alarm")
        }

    }
    
    // Custom implementation of onTapGesture(_:)
    func onTapGestureCustom(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.action = action
        return self
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the `action` variable is not being updated?

Thanks.

Comment: State is for value types.

Comment: @Cora would you know how to achieve what I'm trying to do? I want to set the `action` property in a view modifier type way so it looks like the rest of SwiftUI when I call it.

Comment: This seems like a whole bunch of extra work for what purpose? Can you explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish? I'm playing around with this and none of it is making much sense to me.

Comment: I think what you're attempting to do is pass multiple functions to the button as an action, but that's not 100% clear.

Comment: @xTwisteDx It's so that I can add some additional network related code to the button tap depending on the page it's on. Since `onTapGesture` doesn't work for buttons I'm overriding it so I can simply do `.onTapGesture(action: updateDatabase)`.

Answer (score 0):

By returning a newly created View and changing the `action` variable into a normal instance property makes this work as intended. (Thanks to @Cora for the tip!!)

```
struct ShowAlertButton: View {
    private var action: () -> Void = { print("ALERT!!!") }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // ... some code
            action()
        } label: {
            Text("Sound alarm")
        }

    }
    
    func onTapGestureCustom(_ newValue: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        return ShowAlertButton(action: newValue)
        // or Self(action: newValue)
    }
}
```